# Install elasticsearch v8.5.1 on minikube via helm chart

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I tried installing the elastic/elasticsearch helm chart in my local minikube. The status of pod status is Running 0/1. I have already disabled the xpack.security.enabled=false since it is for development purposes. But the pod still doesn't get running. Is there a configuration I still missing?

```
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-master-0   0/1     Running   0          97m
```

I checked the logs but couln't see any error except warning.

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-02T10:46:35.640Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9200, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:54200}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-master-0][transport_worker][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"xjJ2up7zSGuEnCZ5cz5qDA","elasticsearch.node.id":"vF22sDghRwKJ1fe3sdQirQ","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
```

1. PVC: 2Gi
2. Minikube: kubernetes 1.27.0
3. Helm repo:  https://helm.elastic.co Elasticsearch image: 8.5.1

Values.yml:

```
---
clusterName: "elasticsearch"
nodeGroup: "master"

masterService: ""

roles:
  - master


replicas: 1
minimumMasterNodes: 1

esMajorVersion: ""

esConfig: 
 elasticsearch.yml: |
  xpack:
    security:
      http:
        ssl:
          enabled: false
      autoconfiguration:
        enabled: false
      enabled: false


createCert: true

esJvmOptions: {}
extraEnvs: []

envFrom: []



secret:
  enabled: true
  password: "admin" 


secretMounts: []

hostAliases: []


image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch"
imageTag: "8.1.1"
imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"

podAnnotations: {}


labels: {}

esJavaOpts: "" 
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "2Gi"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "2Gi"

initResources: {}

networkHost: "0.0.0.0"

volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi

rbac:
  create: false
  serviceAccountAnnotations: {}
  serviceAccountName: ""
  automountToken: true

podSecurityPolicy:
  create: false
  name: ""
  spec:
    privileged: true
    fsGroup:
      rule: RunAsAny
    runAsUser:
      rule: RunAsAny
    seLinux:
      rule: RunAsAny
    supplementalGroups:
      rule: RunAsAny
    volumes:
      - secret
      - configMap
      - persistentVolumeClaim
      - emptyDir

persistence:
  enabled: true
  labels:
    enabled: false
  annotations: {}

extraVolumes: []


extraVolumeMounts: []


extraContainers: []


extraInitContainers: []

priorityClassName: ""

antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"

nodeAffinity: {}

enableServiceLinks: true

protocol: http
httpPort: 9200
transportPort: 9300

service:
  enabled: true
  labels: {}
  labelsHeadless: {}
  type: ClusterIP

  publishNotReadyAddresses: false
  nodePort: ""
  annotations: {}
  httpPortName: http
  transportPortName: transport
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  externalTrafficPolicy: ""

updateStrategy: RollingUpdate


maxUnavailable: 1

podSecurityContext:
  fsGroup: 1000
  runAsUser: 1000

securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
      - ALL
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000


terminationGracePeriod: 120

sysctlVmMaxMapCount: 262144

readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 5




schedulerName: ""

imagePullSecrets: []
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []


ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  className: "nginx"
  pathtype: ImplementationSpecific
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
  tls: []


nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
healthNameOverride: ""

lifecycle: {}
sysctlInitContainer:
  enabled: true
keystore: []
networkPolicy:
  elasticsearch-master-transport-client: "true"

  http:
    enabled: false
  transport:
    enabled: false


tests:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: Have you tried using an operator instead? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-eck.html

Comment: Hi Yejin, I have the same issue with HTTP access. Have you resolved?

Answer (score 0):

[Helm chart 8.5.1 for Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/main/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#851) says HTTP access is no longer supported. We have to move to HTTPS access. I haven't tried cert settings yet.

> Security by default for Elasticsearch
> Starting with 8.0.0, Elasticsearch comes with security (TLS + authentication) > enabled and auto-configured by default. Therefore, the Elasticsearch chart  has been updated to generate credentials and TLS certificate by default.  Similarly, all charts have been updated to connect to a secured Elasticsearch deployed by the Elasticsearch chart by default.
>
> Consequently, running the Elasticsearch chart with security disabled isn't anymore supported. The other charts are also not supporting anymore connection to an Elasticsearch without security.
>
> Note that in addition to the security configured by default, it is still possible to use your own TLS certificates, credentials and security configurations (see the security examples for each chart).